# table cell height issue in outlook 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, html, outlook

I am creating email body in the SharePoint desginer approval workflow. 
below is the code that i am using:

[image]

even if i set the height of the cell, in outlook 2013 it is showing bigger cells with fixed height which is not changing no matter what i do.see below pic.

[image]

its really pissing me off. please someone assist me how can i fix this issue. i am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove all the line-break character in the code, the HTML below for your reference:

```
<TABLE width="100%" border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0><TBODY><TR><TD width="165" style="text-align:left;background:#f6f6f6;border-top:1px solid #d8d8d8;font-weight:bold;padding:3px 6px 4px 6px;" vAlign="top">Task Name:</TD><TD width="450" style="text-align:left;background:#f6f6f6;border-top:1px solid #d8d8d8;padding:3px 6px 4px 6px;" id="SPFieldText" vAlign="top">Test2</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

[image]

Comment: no still bigger cells coming up. its working fine in the browser. even the html that i shared is fine in the browser but as long as i m using it as an email template, in the outlook the size is getting messed up.

Comment: Please remove all the line-break character in the code, I modify the code in above , check it.

Comment: oh great. ya it worked. thanks @LOVEZ for ur precious help.